# Seal a window Temporarily (in monsoons)

Tags: home, weather

Almost everyone might have faced few windows that do not close properly , or have little gaps even after closing.

Problem- One set of my Flat room windows falls under opening , we do have a shield on rest of the windows, I cannot build my own due to its flat and owner of building is not interested to solve this problem.

During rain falls even though we close them the water gets inside through few gaps , Now I can fix them with binding them permanently but that will make them closed forever.

I am looking for some temporary solution so that I can apply that in rainy seasons, and I can reopen on a sunny day to dry the moisture in my room.

I have tried fixing few polethene to fill the gaps and close window tightly that works very well however cannot prevent 100% still that makes it less by 80%.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks.SE! Is the plastic seal of the window not leak-proof or does the window frame itself have small holes in it. Does the window not close properly? By `binding them permanently` you mean, that you press them completely shut and then fix them with duct tape or something similar?

Comment: In cold climates, window insulation kits, e.g. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-Indoor-Window-Insulation-Kit-3-per-Pack-V73-3QPD2/100135637, use double-stick tape to hold the polythene, but my hunch is that in *really* humid conditions the tape won't hold.

Comment: Duck Tape? Will that work?

Comment: Could you provide picture(s) of the window(s) display how it leaks? I do not quite understand how and where the gaps are, and pictures might help for you to get proper answers

Comment: @holroy like in this window http://3.imimg.com/data3/RW/VF/MY-4518866/solid-wooden-window-250x250.jpg the bottom portion may create gap with the joints after wear and tear or wrong shape of wood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use water proof gaffer tape. This is a very strong binding tape that will keep out water. The difference between gaffer tape and Duct tape is it is slightly more expensive, however the adhesive element won't leave a residue on the window which can happen with Duct Tape.

Based on your description this should hold up as a temporary measure, and it is easily removed when the weathers nice.

Hope this helps.

**Rossco**

Comment: its a very nice option, however I would like to know in what best way could I apply at the bottom joints of this type window http://3.imimg.com/data3/RW/VF/MY-4518866/solid-wooden-window-250 , 

I am marking this as an answer though seems the best thing :)